# Dispose of nested objects which all implement IDisposable

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have the following code in my project. Do I have to dispose the inner class explicit? If so where?

```
public class Outer : IDisposable
{
    Context context = new Context();
    Inner inner;

    public Outer()
    {
        inner = new Inner(context);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        context.Dispose();
    }
}

public class Inner : IDisposable
{
    Context context;

    public Inner(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Context is something like DbContext from Entity Framework.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, in this case you need to work out what should actually "own" the context. If you've got it in `Inner`, do you really need it in `Outer` as well? Which of them really takes responsibility for them? It looks to me like you really want:

```
public sealed class Outer : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Inner inner;

    public Outer()
    {
        inner = new Inner(new Context());
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        inner.Dispose();
    }
}

public sealed class Inner : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Context context;

    public Inner(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Note that having made both `Outer` and `Inner` sealed, there's no need to write a protected `Dispose(bool disposing)` method etc - that's really for inheritance, which becomes a pain in general. If you *really* need to subclass `Outer` and `Inner` with the possibility of needing to dispose more resources, you'll need a more complicated implementations.

Personally I try *not* to implement `IDisposable` if possible, and keep disposable things only within local variables with `using` statements. It's not always possible of course, but it's worth trying...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is best to Dipsose  `inner`, simply because it implements IDisposable and Outer owns it.

The fact that in this particular setup it can be shown to be superfluous is not important. Inner may later be used in another situation, or change itself. You should isolate you implementation from that.

If anything, you might reconsider if Inner should Dispose of the context. It doesn't create it but gets it passed in. Even better if you could eliminate Inner.context.

Comment: But what happen if both Outer and Inner are disposed? Both are trying to dispose the same resource.

Comment: @Ucodia, that's OK. The contract for Dispose() is that it should be safe to call multiple times. When in doubt, better call it too often than risk the chance of not calling it at all.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, you don't *need* to, since you're already disposing the context.
However, you should dispose it anyway, in case `Inner.Dispose` ever changes.

In general, you should err on the side of disposing things.
Disposing the same object twice won't cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you should also implement IDisposable correctly.

```
  private bool _disposed;

  public void Dispose()
  {
     Dispose(true);
     GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
  }

  protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
     if (!_disposed)
     {
        if (disposing)
        {
           // Managed
           inner.Dispose();
        }

        // Unmanaged
     }

     _disposed = true;
  }

  ~Outer()
  {
     Dispose(false);
  }
```

Comment: There's no indication that a finalizer is really needed here, or indeed the "full" pattern. Personally I would seal both Outer and Inner, at which point there's no need for anything more complicated than a simple Dispose method.

Comment: Isn't a finalizer that only calls dispose pointless (or even harmful)? Finalizers are a last resort for native resources. Class wrapping native resources should implement a finalizer and IDisposable. Objects only containing other IDisposable objects don't need a finalizer, they can rely on the finalizers of inner objects.

Comment: My answer stems from rule CA1063 [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244737%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).  But I agree, if you just seal the types then there is no need for the full pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the pasted code it's the Outer class which should Dispose of the context. It's great if you can keep allocation and disposing close together. The lifetime of the context object can be very sanely be managed by the Outer class.

It's a bad idea to dispose all the objects you can reach. You should only dispose those objects you allocated yourself.

Disposing in the Inner class can also mean you can't use the Outer object after you dispose the Inner object. This is fine in the sample you posted but not generally.